# JavaScript prompt window disappears when navigating to other tab

Tags: javascript, function, prompt, password-protection

I have written following snippet to enable password on my site, but if I navigate to different tab on the browser, the password prompt disappears and this feature is not useful anymore.

```
 function passWord(title) {

       var pwd = prompt(title);

       switch (pwd) {
         case '2017': true;
           break;

         case null: passWord('Access Denied - Password Incorrect, Please Try Again.');
           break;

         default: passWord('Access Denied - Password Incorrect, Please Try Again.');
       }
     }
```

I am calling this function in body tag.

```
   <body onload="passWord('Please enter password here')">
```

Comment: The correct way is create authentication to server password protected data securely from your server, client side javascript isn't security.

Comment: Thanks @CelebBlack. I am just looking for a short time solution, but yeah you are absolutely right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this method:

```
<style>#screen {display: none;}</style>
<body onload="passWord();">
  <div id="welcome">
    <h1>Welcome Page</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="screen">
    <h1>Unique Page</h1>
  </div>
  <script>
    function passWord() {
      var welcome = document.getElementById("welcome");    
      var screen = document.getElementById("screen");
      var pwd = prompt("Enter your password", "TYPE HERE");
      switch(pwd) {
        case "2017":
          screen.style.display = "block";
          welcome.style.display = "none";
        break;
        default:
          screen.style.display = "none";
          welcome.style.display = "block";
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

As @Caleb Black comment - It's better using php for this things if security matter. Good Luck!

Comment: @AMeshu I don't understand how your function solves the problem of disappearing of prompt event. Can you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: It's another approach: hide the content unless the user enter correct password.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `focus` event to see when the users comes back to your page:

```
var didEnterPassword = false;

window.addEventListener("focus", function(e){
    if(!didEnterPassword && prompt("hello again") == "my secret password"){
        didEnterPassword = true;
    }
})
```

Keep in mind though that this is **incredibly insecure** since anyone can get `my secret password` when they start digging in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a while loop which keeps running as long as the user hasn't sent their answer:

```
var pwd;
while(pwd == null) pwd = prompt(title);
```

Note that it will not preserve any text entered before the focus was lost.